# How do I save m2m field session from a form to another?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm doing a multi step form where everything is saved at the end. In my models I have a m2m checkbox field and I'm using django Sessions to grab the forms datas to show it on the final step.

The issue is that the m2m field (checkboxes) is not saved when I submit the final form.

Here is my views file :

**views.py**

```
def step1(request):
    initial={'name': request.session.get('name', None), 'checkbox': request.session.get('checkbox', (False,))} #cookies
    form = FormOneForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            request.session['name'] = form.cleaned_data['name']
            request.session['checkbox'] = form.cleaned_data.get('checkbox')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('step2'))
    return render(request, 'step1.html', {'form': form})

def step2(request):
    form = FormTwoForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            formtwo = form.save(commit=False)
            formone2 = FormOne.objects.create(checkbox=request.session.get('checkbox')) #error is here
            formone = FormOne.objects.create(name=request.session['name'])
            formtwo.owner = formone
            formtwo.save()
            formone2.save_m2m()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('step3'))

    return render(request, 'step2.html', {'form': form})
```

**models.py**

```
class Font(models.Model):
    font_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    font_family = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    font_link = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...

class FormOne(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    checkbox = models.ManyToManyField(Font, blank=True)
    ...

class FormTwo(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey(FormOne)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    ...
```

this code gives me this error :

```
'checkbox' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

How can I achieve what I am trying to realise ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to save object first:

```
formone2 = FormOne.objects.create(name=request.session['name'])
formone2.checkbox.add(request.session.get('checkbox')
```

The problem is that you need to save object before use Many-to-many relations. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/):

> You can’t associate it with a Publication until it’s been saved